# Rename Currency field Label in a Multi-Currency enabled Org

Tags: custom-object, standard-objects, configuration, multi-currency

I have an Org where Multi-Currency is enabled. I can see Currency field available for objects. But I need to change the Currency field label to some other label of one of the custom object. I don't see an option to rename its label. I checked 'Rename Tabs and Labels' option, I also checked the field itself, it doesn't have any option to rename it.
Any idea!

Comment: do you want to change the label of Field or Object or Tab??

Comment: @Mr.Frodo, It's field label which I want to change.

Comment: What happens when you click edit on field, I think it should allow you to change the label, although when you change the label it gives you  a warning but i think still you can do it.

Comment: @Mr.Frodo There is no button called 'edit' for currency field. Only two buttons I can see: 1. 'Set Field-Level Security' and 'View Field Accessibility'.

Comment: Then probably you don't have rights to edit the field. What is your Salesforce profile?? You can check in your profile that whether you have permission to edit field or not.

Comment: I'm System Admin. I can see the edit button for other fields. It's just Currency field where I can't find the edit button.

Comment: What's the API name for the field? Are you talking about the CurrencyISOCode field? As I believe that is a system field and cannot be renamed - though you could globally rename it through translation work bench?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to go to Setup>Rename Tabs and Labels and then click Edit next to the object the field is on. Once you click Next, you'll have the ability to edit standard field labels.